# cannot access value of attribute using xpath

Tags: xpath, attributes

I am not able to get a value of second attribute based on first attribute.
I try to get value of content attribute. i.e. `4,450` out of following XML:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content=" 4,450" />
```

Tried with this XPath: `//meta[@itemprop=\"price\"][@content]`
But I'm getting output similar to the input XML.

Comment: Consider accepting on of the provided answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need a slash before the `content` attribute:

```
//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content
```

Answer (score 3):

The usage is incorrect.

Use the following code

```
//meta[@itemprop=\"price\"]/@content
```